# Issue with a specific mysql query

Tags: mysql, where-clause

This is the query for a gaming application to get a list of targets for the enemy that excludes locations that the enemy can't see.  This is a simplified version of my query to target my specific question.

```
SELECT * FROM `game_moblist` WHERE  (posx!=0 AND posy!=0) AND (posx!=1100 AND posy!=220)
```

posx is the x coordinate posy is the y coordinate

I'm writing a loop to exclude any tiles that cannot be seen
The issue I see is that its treated as if the parenthesis aren't there.  All posx=1100 are excluded and not the ordered pair (1100,220) what is the proper syntax for what I'm trying to do?  The only solution I thought of is to combine the two numbers into a unique single number but I'd rather learn something new.

Comment: Not sure if it's that simple, but note that `(posx!=1100 AND posy!=220)` is not the same as `(!(posx=1100 AND posy=220))`

Comment: @neokio: I think you nailed the issue. Post it as an answer and I'll delete mine

Comment: @ypercube thx for offer, but you were more thorough :) also, your `NOT IN` query is awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
WHERE NOT (posx=0 AND posy=0) 
  AND NOT (posx=1100 AND posy=220)
```

which can be rewritten also as:

```
WHERE (posx, posy) NOT IN ((0, 0), (1100, 200))
```

Comment: +1 TIL how to do a multi-column `IN` / `NOT IN` comparison! =D

Comment: yeah exactly what I was loooking for.